# Concatenate column values for specific fields while displaying other column values in Oracle 11.2

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, string-concatenation, string-aggregation

I am a SQL noob.

How can I concatenate column values for specific fields while displaying other column values?

I will try my best to show a simplified example.

Say I have the following table:

### Table A

| Name | Address | Email | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | 123 Main Street | sam@coporate.com | 34 | 51 | 39 |
| Peter | 789 High Street | peter@coporate.com | 73 | 05 | 59 |
| Sam | 123 Main Street | sam@coporate.com | 43 | 12 | 84 |
| Sally | 456 State Street | sally@coporate.com | 35 | 76 | 23 |
| Sally | 456 State Street | sally@coporate.com | 77 | 34 | 18 |
| Peter | 789 High Street | peter@coporate.com | 32 | 14 | 54 |
| Sally | 456 State Street | sally@coporate.com | 64 | 49 | 23 |

### Expected output

| Name | Address | Email | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | 123 Main Street | sam@coporate.com | 34,43 | 51,12 | 39,84 |
| Sally | 456 State Street | sally@coporate.com | 35,64,77 | 76,49,34 | 23,23,18 |
| Peter | 789 High Street | peter@coporate.com | 32,73 | 14,05 | 54,59 |

I tried using `LISTAGG` but the issue I had was that I was then not able to display the Name, Address and Email fields. Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to add an [analytic clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) to the function for this instead of `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, EMAIL,
    LISTAGG(value1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value1) new_value_1,
    LISTAGG(value2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value2) new_value_2,
    LISTAGG(value3, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value3) new_value_3
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY NAME, ADDRESS, EMAIL;
```

I have my compiler into job computer, I am not sure. If I wrong, tell me to drop answer please.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select name, address, email,
       listagg (value1, ',') within group (order by name) as values1,
       listagg (value2, ',') within group (order by name) as values2,
       listagg (value3, ',') within group (order by name) as values3
from a
group by name, address, email;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d2bb0ba5c6ce277a5f65ad4e74f9e5a) is a db<>fiddle.